# How do I render nth columns on every row using React JS?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to render 4 divs (with class .col-4) in every row div in React JS.

This is what I've already tried:

```
 return (
    <Styles>
    <div className="container add-page">
      <input className="add-movie container" type="text" placeholder="Search for movies" value={query} onChange={onChange} />
      </div>
      {results.length > 0 && (
         results.map((movie) => (
         
             if(rows%4===0){
              <div className="row">
                <ResultCard movie={movie} key={movie.id} /> 
               
             }
             rows++;
             if(rows%columns===0){
            </div>}
      
        ))
      )}

    </Styles>
  )
```

But, I'm getting an unexpected token error in the line where I am using if statement. I guess it's got something to do with the JSX syntax.

This is the what the ResultCard Component's return looks like:

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Styles>
        {movie.poster_path ? (
          <div className="col-4">
            <img
              src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200/${movie.poster_path}`}
              alt={`${movie.title} Poster`}
              height="300"
              width="200"
            />

            <Button variant="success">Add to Watchlist</Button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="col-4">
            <img
              src={NotFound}
              height="300"
              width="200"
              alt="Poster not found"
            />
          </div>
        )}
      </Styles>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
```

Basically, I want to have a row div and render 4 ResultCard Components in that row div. Then, I want to create another row div for other 4 ResultCard Components and so on and so forth.

P.S: I know there are a few similar questions on this site, but in those questions, the OPs' code was structured in such a way that the answers to those questions solved their problems but are not working for me. That's why I'm asking this here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React JSX is not HTML, and it's not a string either. It's translated directly to JS. So you can'y render an opening tag, render a bunch of items, and then close the tag.

You'll have to render the container, and then render the items inside it. To do so you'll need to split (chunk) the `results` array to sub-arrays, render the `.row` container, and then map the items inside it.

To chunk the items, you can use `Array.from()` with `Array.slice()`:

```js
const Demo = ({ results }) => (
  <div>
  {results.length > 0 && (
    Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(results.length / 4) }, (_, i) => (
      <div className="row" key={`row${i}`}>
      {
        results.slice(i * 4, (i + 1) * 4)
          .map((movie) => (
            <div className="card" key={movie}>{movie}</div>
          ))
      }
      </div>
    ))
  )}
  </div>
)

const movies = ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2', 'A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3', 'A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4'];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo results={movies} />,
  root
);
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 2px solid gold;
}

.card {
  width: 24%;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

A simpler option, that will save you the need to manipulate the arrays, is to render all the items as a list, and display them using CSS grid:

```js
const Demo = ({ results }) => (
  <div className="grid">
  {results.length > 0 && (
    results.map((movie) => (
      <div className="card" key={movie}>{movie}</div>
    ))
  )}
  </div>
)

const movies = ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2', 'A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3', 'A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4'];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo results={movies} />,
  root
);
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

.card {
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Well, the second solution doesn't work for me as I'm getting the error: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Comment: Not that I've simplified the data structure for this demo. In my case a `movie` is a string, in your case an object.

Comment: So, how do I get around that issue? The results is an array and yeah, movie is an object. but objects are not valid as react child? Maybe, I can create other component, render it and give movie prop?

Comment: Render your `ResultCard` and pass the object to it instead of my `<div className="card" key={movie}>{movie}</div>`. The card is fine, the row is the redundant part in the 2nd solution.

Comment: The grid method is freakin genius!!  So simple!!

Answer (score 0):

U cant have if statements inside of jsx, so have your map function outside of return and then just put what u want to return {mapMovies}

```js
const mapMovies = results.length > 0 && (
         results.map((movie) => (
         
             if(rows%4===0){
              <div className="row">
                <ResultCard movie={movie} key={movie.id} /> 
               

             rows++;
             if(rows%columns===0){ %>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm still getting the error in the if statement (the first one)